# Unable to load Maven meta-data from private repo. Received 403: Forbidden

Tags: maven, react-native

I'm trying append a private dependency into my project (react-native-android) via Maven. Unfortunately I'm get following error message when I try to build `./gradlew assembleDebug` my project.

**Error message returned as below:**

```
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:0.19.+.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-i18n
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://xxxPRIVATE_REPOxxx/android/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://xxxPRIVATE_REPOxxx/android/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://xxxPRIVATE_REPOxxx/android/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

**Code example**

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    maven { url "https://xxxPRIVATE_REPOxxx/android" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-i18n')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    implementation 'xxxPRIVATE_DEPENDENCYxxx:1.0.+'
}
```

I have read numerous post and research on maven and gradle's topic. Here's my finding towards my issues:

1. Meaning that my [sequence of declaring maven](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html) by right will get the "correct/suitable" module from the first declared maven instead of the following (maven xxxPRIVATE_REPOxxx)

   > The order of declaration determines how Gradle will check for dependencies at runtime. If Gradle finds a module descriptor in a particular repository, it will attempt to download all of the artifacts for that module from the same repository. You can learn more about the inner workings of dependency downloads.
2. Returning of 403 Forbidden does not necessary mean I do not have access to the repo I'm trying to access, but also [missing of resource](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5606).

Hence I made an assumption here... During the download of project dependencies, Maven loop through both maven repo (maven google & xxxPRIVATE_REPOxxx) to get the suitable lib. However when it reaches xxxPRIVATE_REPOxxx, it failed to locate maven-metadata.xml therefore result with  *https://xxxPRIVATE_REPOxxx/android/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml* and 403 Forbidden.

**My question:**

Should there be a way to indicate which dependency to get from which Maven?

I was imaging something like this
`implementation 'xxxPRIVATE_DEPENDENCYxxx:1.0.+' : xxxPRIVATE_REPOxxx` (You know what I mean)

**I have tried:**

1. Upgrading my Android-Plugin to 3.5.0
2. Upgrading my Gradle version to 5.6.4
3. ./gradlew clean and re-build after steps 1 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was because the react native dependencies use by 3rd party library (react-native-i18n) was too low. *You can find it at react-native-i18n's build.gradle.*

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.12.+'
}
```

Hence my fix to this was update the code to

```
compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
```